# fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php returns a 1x1 image

Tags: json, image, facebook-graph-api

In my facebook reader app my picture sometimes doesn't show, this is because of fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php won't render it.

I've taken the links from the JSON below, it's ony the relevant part of the JSON reply.

```
  "message": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJer7-eAy3o", 
  "picture": "https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCMr5crfpv0x3lm&w=130&h=130&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi3.ytimg.com\u00252Fvi\u00252FRJer7-eAy3o\u00252Fmqdefault.jpg", 
  "link": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJer7-eAy3o", 
  "source": "http://www.youtube.com/v/RJer7-eAy3o?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1", 
  "name": "Dougie MacLean - Broken Wings", 
  "caption": "www.youtube.com", 
  "description": "Dougie MacLean's 'Broken Wings' performed with strings at The Perthshire Amber Festival, October 2005.", 
  "icon": "https://s-static.ak.facebook.com/rsrc.php/v2/yj/r/v2OnaTyTQZE.gif"
```

The problem is the `https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQCMr5crfpv0x3lm&w=130&h=130&url=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fi3.ytimg.com\u00252Fvi\u00252FRJer7-eAy3o\u00252Fmqdefault.jpg` part.

If I visit http://i3.ytimg.com/u00252Fvi/RJer7-eAy3o/mqdefault.jpg it shows the correct image, so that can't be the problem. Am I doing something wrong or is the `safe_image.php` just buggy and should I just strip the url to it's original url and use that?

Tnx and greets,
Sjaak

Comment: oh and sorry if this seems like a duplicate, I found a bunch of similar questions, but the anwsers with those were either wrong or contained dead links to the old facebook developer forum.

Comment: This looks a bit like a bug report... You might want to consider filing it with Facebook - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Comment: I've already seen it posted there, it's even said so have been resolved several times. But might as well bring it to their attention again...

Comment: Then you should subscribe to that bug and explain your recreation procedures.  This site is not run by Facebook... We are just normal users... Posting a Facebook bug on Stack Overflow is not going to get Facebook's attention - If it already exists in their bug system and they *say* that its fixed - there is nothing we ([so]) can do about it...

Comment: I am not expecting SO to fix this, I know that's not gonna happen. I was hoping someone knew some sort of workaround or perhaps something I've overlooked. Since the replies on the bugreports are also a bit hazy. Almost looks like facebook is trying to ignore this one :P

Answer (score 0):

I also get into a similar problem. My problem is because of the image name has a "space" in it. so it is not appear in the [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) and also in sharing. But i checked with your problem, there is no space in it. so its not the solution for the above problem. It will help another one similar to my issue.

I fixed the issue by replace space with hyphen("-") through coding part. After that i debug the url in [facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug), it appears. That means Facebook wont show the image name with "space". But there is no logical reason behind this. Anyway it will help someone.

For more information check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25216164/3049065) posted by [Patrick D'appollonio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012139/patrick-dappollonio). It helps me.