# 1x1 px og image facebook

Tags: html, facebook-graph-api, metadata

So i have used the og tags several times and have successfully been able to share blog posts with custom images, but for some reason, I can't figure this one out.

According to fb debugger, all of my meta tags are correct, and I'm getting a 200 code. Even the Raw open graph document information shows the full correct path of the image I have added with the http prefix, which if i copy and paste on a new tab, will take me to the correct image. But the image in the object properties is replaced by a 1x1 px dot that I can only see if I inspect the element.
I know that the whole og thing has been talked about over and over again, but i could not find an answer anywhere for this weird 1x1 px problem.
The link i am trying is http://ladyilgphotography.businesscatalyst.com/lady-ilg-journal/casper-and-maggie-beautiful-wedding-grant-humphrys-mansion-wedding

Thank you for any help you might have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's probably a problem with the image url not being properly escaped on the opengraph tag.

At the end, the `og:image` has a space and then parenthesis... But it isn't escaped on the HTML code: `http://ladyilgphotography.businesscatalyst.com/images/journal/love/weddings/Casper and Maggie--wedding/best_wedding_photographer_in_denver (16).jpg` So once the Facebook fetcher script tries to access that URL, it's probably not going to find it...

Have you tried escaping the filename in that URL?

Comment: I'll just be totally honest and admit two things: first is, that actually makes sense. Two is I have no idea what or how escaping is or works. I am assuming you mean getting rid of the special characters and replacing them by their code? if so, how could i do that here? the file path is generated dynamically through a css.

Comment: Ok i looked it up and I guess i was at least somewhat correct. I tried a small function where i do encodeURI("image path"), but how can i pass the function's return value to the meta tag? Is it possible to use variables in a meta tag?

Comment: You're saying that the image path is been generated by CSS. That's kind of impossible because CSS is not a server side scripting language. In what language you're doing your web page? Is that PHP or just pure and plain HTML?

Comment: Patrick. I am sorry, I meant to write it's generated dynamically through the CMS, not css... big difference. In any case, I was hoping there was a js solution to doing this, but i found that facebook fetches the info on the server side without running any js of course. So to make things easier I am just going to have to rename all of the folders and files to not include any spaces. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If the CMS is tailor made, you could theoretically still be able to edit that but it's kind of hard. Glad I could help!